# Segmentation fault? What am I doing wrong?

Tags: c++, qt, segmentation-fault

I am new to C++, so I have some troubles. I am working on a project to improve my skills with Qt. I run into a problem:

```
1. filename = event->mimeData()->urls().at(0).toLocalFile();
2. filename = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this,tr("Load Image"), "C:/", tr("Image Files (*.png)"));
3. filename = QString(event->mimeData()->urls().at(0).toLocalFile());
```

filename is a class member of type QString (not a pointer nor reference) declared in the header file of my class.

All three examples are compiling, but 1. gives me a segmentation fault, whereas 2. and 3. don't. Can somebody explain this to me? Especially why 2. and 1. end up in two different endings.

My understanding so far was that toLocalFile() returns a QString which is not a reference nor pointer. filename uses the = operator to assign this string and return a reference. I thought: "maybe the QString object is not copied and thus referencing a variable which will be destroyed by the end of the block --> bad", so I used the Copy constructor of QString to make a copy. And it worked. BUT getOpenFileName() does exactly the same thing, it returns a QString etc. Somehow this doesn't blow up. 
Just that you get a better understanding of my problem and my thinking.

Thanks ;)

Comment: are your 100% sure that `event->mimeData()->urls()` returns a list that is not empty?

Comment: toLocalFile() already returns a QString, so I don’t see how 1 vs. 3 should make a difference. Check in your debugger what exactly goes wrong, Like @Zaiborg I'd suspect at(0) is called on an empty list (which should also crash 3, but maybe you accidentally tested it with different mimedata).

Comment: I'm pretty sure, that urls() returns a non-empty list because I make sure of it by calling if(event->mimeData()->hasUrls()) first.